# What is the discrete log used for?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, soft-question

Perusing Wikipedia, I stumbled on the [discrete logarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm).  I looks interesting that we'd be able have a function that could solve $b^k=g$ for integers $b,k,$ and $g$.  However, Wikipedia says "No efficient classical algorithm for computing general discrete logarithms $\log_bg$ is known."  I'm just wondering, if we can't calculate it (except by trial and error with presumably small numbers, is this even a useful concept?  What can we do with the discrete logarithm?

Comment: Solve Diffie-Hellman protocol for data exchanging with no shared secret.

Comment: Many cryptography schemes rely on the fact that discrete logarithm is difficult to calculate.

Comment: From your comment about "presumably small numbers" it is not clear if you realize that the equation $b^k = g$ is not in the integers, but is really a congruence to some modulus: $b^k \equiv g \bmod p$.

Comment: @KCd Oh, so $b^k-g = pn$ for some integer $n$?

Comment: Yes, but the point is that when working in modular arithmetic, exponentiation can be done without the output getting explosively large (beyond the size of the modulus) and can be carried out efficiently.

Answer (score 1):

We could break Diffie-Hellman protocol for data exchange with no shared secret.

**Public Information:**

- Prime number $p$
- Generator $g\in{Z}^*p$

**Protocol:**

[image]

**Advantage of Alice and Bob over Eve:**

- Alice and Bob can easily compute $k=g^{ab}$
- Eve intercepts $g^a$ and $g^b$, but cannot easily compute $g^{ab}$

**Assumptions:**

[image]